# Can I use "fail" as intransitive verb in the following way?

Tags: transitivity

according to this source:

"https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/fail"

a:to disappoint the expectations or trust of:

her friends failed her

b:to miss performing an expected service or function for
his wit failed him

so accordint to b: could I rewrite the:

"his wit failed him" to: "his wit failed for him" making fail  intransitive?

Comment: Why would you do this?

Comment: Sure, his wit failed him. Anything or anyone can fail you.

Comment: @henryke araudjo I would also ask why you would want to do this.

Comment: @all I would like to know first of all if that would be semantically correct. secondly I'm practicing the use of preposition. It's hard for me to use the right preposition in a sentence. when build a setence mentally I aways think of it using preposition

Answer (score 0):

No, as the dictionary says this is a transitive use of the verb "fail".  In this transitive use, the subject is the thing that was expected to perform a service, and the direct object is the person for whom the service would have been done.

The object in this sense is a direct object. None of the intransitive senses could apply to "His wit failed for him".

Comment: according to this definition: "to miss performing an expected service or function for" there is a "for" in it I thought I could use it in rewriting, I thought that is how it would works

Comment: Yes, the transitive form of "fail" can be glossed as a phrase ending with "for".... that doesn't mean the intransative form of of "fail" can have take a "for...." prepositional phrase. (it also doesn't mean it's impossible, but consult the dictionary, a you see that it doesn't).  I can probably find more examples like this.

Comment: So it's OK to use: "his wit failed for him"  as a transitive form right?

Comment: No.... That is intransitive.  There is no direct object.  The correct form is "His wit failed him".  This sense **requires** a direct object.  If you don't have a direct object it doesn't mean the same.